# Prevent django-simple-history from creating permissions?

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-simple-history

Too many models spamming django permission table, even in models where I dont need permissions.
I use django-simple-history, and django creates permssions on these historical tables. How can I avoid it?
I've tried passing the `bases` option to `HistoricalRecords()`, passed an abstract class with
`default_permissions = []` in its Meta. Didnt work. Any solution?

In fact I would even prefer if django wont create permissions at all on every migrate...

Comment: Why is it a problem for Django to create these permissions? They won't have any noticeable effect in terms of disk space or performance. You might be able to prevent Django from creating the permissions, but it might not be worth the complexity that it adds to your app.

Comment: I have a UI for adding permissions for users, so I need to know what are my 'real' permissions, and what are django ones which I don't want to display. I've created a one-to-one table for that. Larger the auth.permission table is, harder for me to maintain

Comment: I would try to filter the list of permissions in the UI, rather than trying to stop the permissions from being created. The `Permission` model has a foreign key to `ContentType` which has an app label field. You could either whitelist or blacklist the permissions for different apps by using `filter()` or `exclude()` respectively.

Comment: I cant filter by app because django create useless permissions for every model. That's why I have one to one table

Comment: Maybe you can filter on the model name then - it looks like django-simple-history prefixes model names with 'historical'.